# What does this icon in Outlook 2013 mean?

Tags: windows, email, icons, outlook-2013

Does anyone know what this Outlook 2013 icon means? My Google skills are failing me this morning

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found this](https://superuser.com/questions/626801/why-does-outlook-2013-not-send-my-email)

Although I do not use Outlook 2013, this other forum appears to say that the icon is for drafts/edited emails in the "outbox". For some reason, it prevents you from sending that email, and disabling add-ins should fix it (they mention iCloud was the add-in which created the issue in that case).

By the way, I searched "outlook 2013 paper and pencil icon" haha.

Comment: Answering questions with just a link is not very useful since the link might go away eventually, after which the answer isn't an answer anymore.